# Fast way to map unrelated values to another value

Tags: c

What is a fast way (in C) to get a corresponding value based on other value from a set of completely unrelated values?

Example:

The values {0xFE, 0x84, 0x35} correspond to values {0, 1, 2}, which are used to index an array of functions.

```
void doStuff(int weirdValue)
{
  int correspondingIndex = getIndexFromWeirdValue(weirdValue);

  doMoreStuff[correspondingIndex]();
}
```

I know that I can use values {0, 1, 2} to index an array and access {0xFE, 0x84, 0x35} through it, but is there any way to do the reverse operation without having to iterate through the set comparing values if these values are to be statically associated?

Comment: Depends on the nature of the association. Is it static or dynamic?

Comment: Static. Will edit the question, thanks.

Comment: Hashmaps do this in near-constant time, but they are not trivial to implement. Iterating the set is the simplest option, and if it's only a few elements, you'll notice no difference

Answer (score 1):

*Associative Arrays*, also called *Maps* or *Hashed Maps* or *Red-Black-Trees* would be the right solution for large amounts. Google 'std:map' for more details (that is C++, but you can use the concept, of course you have to implement it yourself)

For small amounts (maybe up to 20 or 30), a simple loop through is even faster, as there is no hashing overhead.

Answer (score 1):

In the above example, domain of values is 8 bit so you can have an array of 256 values for that. Similarly if you a set of thousand values, you can simply have an array of that size. Although, this approach will be rough on memory, but it will give O(1) time complexity.

If the domain and range of values is unknown, then a hashtable/hashmap can be implemented. Although, that would be hard to implement but it will give O(1) time complexity.

Iteration would be easy to implement, but O(n) time complexity would be there.

Comment: An almost complete answer. The only option I'm missing is using a sorted array + binary search which would come out to O(log(n)) complexity. (Equal to using a balanced tree but much better memory access / cache friendlier.)

Comment: How would it be O(log(n))? Wouldn't the cost of sorting or balancing add up? You mean something like TreeMap in java? A balanced red-black tree.

Comment: Since the data doesn't change in this scenario, it only needs to be sorted once and for all. This can (and should) be done even before the program is started: Simply sort the array in the source code.

Comment: Sounds good...but I couldn't find..how will you keep mapping of values?

Comment: You use an array of (*key*, *value*) pairs, sorted by *key*. As you found the entry with the matching *key* through binary search, you look up the *value* in the same entry. Equivalently, you could also use two arrays; one for the keys and one for the values. As you fond the index in the sorted key-array, you look up the same index in the value array.

Answer (score 0):

With only 3 possible input values mapping to 3 consecutive values.

```
int getIndexFromWeirdValue(int x) {
  static const int x[3] = {0xFE, 0x84, 0x35};
  static const int y[3] = {0,1,2};
  return (x==x[0])*y[0] + (x==x[1])*y[1] + (x==x[2])*y[2];
}
```

Other methods exist that perform in a similar non-branching fashion.

Using 4-byte math to map 1 byte to 1 byte and `x[]` are distinct, always an answer of the form below can be made - fast if `int` division is fast  YMMV.  C0, C1, C2, D based on mapping.  If mapping is constant, these values can be determined at compile time.

```
y = (((C0*x + C1)*x + C2)/D + y[0];
```